# Creating an alert value in tableau

Tags: alert, tableau-api, calculated-field

I'm interested in tracking club members to view meeting attendance.  I've got names in rows and the dates of the meetings as columns, with their attendance (binary, for 1 attended, 0 for didn't) marks.

What would be a good way to highlight poor attendance?
For example, if someone misses 2 in a row, would a calculated field be a good way to go? I'm not sure how to code it w/o having FOR loops.  I would want to have it check a date against the previous date (if it's within filter range), and if they're both a miss, turn them both red or otherwise indicate the poor attendance.

Any ideas/advice?

Answer (score 1):

I’m sure there are a few ways you could go about doing this, some more suitable depending on your use case.  Assuming that your data is tidy, (in that a member has a record for every possible meeting date) a simple way would be to create a calculated field, let’s say “Indicator”

```
Rows: “Name”
Columns: “Date” (Discrete)
Color: Indicator
Mark Type: Square
Indicator (definition):
IF WINDOW_SUM(SUM([Present]),-1,0) = 0 AND INDEX() != 1
THEN 2
ELSEIF SUM([Present]) = 0
THEN 1
ELSE 0  
END
```

[image]

Depending on the number of members and meeting dates, you may want to aggregate further to ask questions such as:

"Which Members have more than 5 consecutive absences in the past year"

More complicated calculations could be done using Level of Details (LOD), advanced table calculations etc…however, I’ve found it easier to do the data preparation before tableau, so that I have more flexibility in easily answering a question later.  In this case I would recommend merging the previous attendance value to each record in the form of an additional column.

Speaking more generally about your problem, I think that a count of missed meetings for each person across the time period, normalized against the average of all members should be sufficient to highlight those members with poor attendance.